How to change the cursor thickness on Insert modes in Vim?
How to change the cursor thickness on Insert and Replace modes vertically and horizontally, respectively in Vim?
The init.lua has
vim.opt.guicursor='n-v-sm-i-ci-ve:block,i:ver41,r:hor41,a:blinkoff400-blinkon250-Cursor/lCursor'

which fails to set thickness
Please sincerely guide to correct path up to solve it
